# What Movie catalog software is available?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm currently using Ant Movie Catalog in Windows, is there any similar apps in Linux (preferably open source)? I'm trying to move away from XP and trying migrate my apps from XP to Linux/Ubuntu. I understand that you could install under Wine, the trouble is I'm still learning and never used Wine before, so if it's possible, I'd like to avoid using it at this moment.

Answer (score 4):

1. You can try CeeMedia, they have a .deb package.

Just download it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ceemedia/files/

[image]

2. There's also Griffith avaiable on the Ubuntu Software Center

[image]

3. [GCStar](http://www.gcstar.org/) looks pretty good

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot with this tips, I've installed and imported AMC's file into GCStar, now I'm trying to figure out how to make GCStar to display Chinese char.